# Use generated string inside jQuery Filter

Tags: jquery, filter

I am trying to bring a generated string as a working filter condition to jQuery Filter.

What I've done so far:

```js
const elements = 3;

let foundMatch = false;
let line = "";

// generate a filter condition per element count
for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
  line += "$(this).find('.segment:eq(" + i + ")').data('stops') <= filterData.stops[" + i + "] && ";
}            


// combine the generated filter conditions with the existing one
for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
  console.log(line);

  foundMatch = foundMatch ||                    
    $("input[type='radio']:eq(0)").is(":checked") &&
    line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="abc" checked />
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="def" />
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="xyz" />
```

But this seems not to work. How do I combine the string with the existing filter condition the correct way, so that the filter function can work again?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/6zt8Lgh5/16/

Comment: I've edited your question to include a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552); this makes it easier for people to see your code in action, and copy your code to an answer and fix it.

Comment: You can't really execute strings. Why not just include that code in your string as actual code in your second `for` loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's what I've tried first. But it looked as if it would run too less times

Comment: @HereticMonkey Can you tell me how to get a filter condition like this ==>  $("#static").val == "10" && $(".sample:eq(0)").val() == "1") && $(".sample:eq(1)").val() == "1")

Comment: ... Type that into the code?

Comment: @HereticMonkey But the amount of elements can be totally different. There can be 1 element or 10 or even more..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and any and all requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code :

```js
const elements = 3;

const isMatchFound = () => {
  let conditions = [];
  
  conditions.push($("#input[type'radio']:eq(0").is(":checked"));

  for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    conditions.push($(document).find(".segment:eq(" + i + ")").data("stops") <= filterData.stops[i]);
  }
  
  // for test purposes
  //conditions = [true, true, false]; => false
  //conditions = [true, true, true]; => true
  return conditions.every(a => a === true);
};

const foundMatch = isMatchFound();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="abc" checked />
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="def" />
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="xyz" />
```

You populate an array of condition results, and then check if all the conditions are `true`.

---

This solution uses [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
, a method that tests if each element in the array passes the test you provide as a parameter.

Here, my test is `a => a === true`, which is ES6's [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions)
. Basically, this is just another way to write `function (a) { return a === true; }`.

So, the test is simply to check if the provided variable (which I named `a` in this case) is strictly equal to `true`.

Comment: YOU ARE A STAR !! This is awesome, cause it's easy to understand, easy to configure, easy to adopt and very readable....!! YOU SAVED MY WEEK - thank you so much!!

Comment: PS, can you explain  return conditions.every(a => a === true);  to me? What does every do and what does a => a mean? I have never seen or even used that before!

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi I just edited my answer to add more explanation on what is used.

Comment: Superb! Thanks a lot