# Combining static and dynamic values to a filter condition

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I need to combine a few filter conditions, static and dynamic ones (dynamic ones of unknown amount, can vary from 1 to 10 or even more). How can this be done? I always get wrong results and I have the feeling, the for loop runs only with one dynamic condition at a time. Thanks for any idea!

```js
const Count = 3;
 
for (let i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
  $("#static").val == "10" && $(".sample:eq(" + i + ")").val() == "1");
}
```

should result in:

```
$("#static").val() == "10" && 
$(".sample:eq(0)").val() == "1") && 
$(".sample:eq(1)").val() == "1") && 
$(".sample:eq(2)").val() == "1")
```

Comment: Firstly, there's a syntax error in the question. Secondly, that is not how conditions work. As such this is an X/Y question where you've asked about your attempted solution instead of describing what the issue is you're trying to solve. If you can edit the question to do that we can provide you with some answers, as even with this working I can guarantee you there is better ways to achieve what you need

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I've fixed the syntax error and what I am expecting is written in the example.  Ahh, I see Tyler Roper has optimized the question. Thanks for that!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times... Edit [your older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907749/215552).

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi I can see what's written, but it makes very little sense for the reasons I described in my first comment.

Comment: So essentially what you're looking to do is take a handful of elements, and ask the question "Does this statement hold true for every single item"? Just check the static one first. If it's `"10"`, then check that all the others are `"1"` using some implementation of `.every()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use generated string inside jQuery Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907749/use-generated-string-inside-jquery-filter)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right. I have updated my question

Comment: @TylerRoper I've never used .every() ... need to check how this works.

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi We could help you out but you'll need to address Rory's initial comment. Your condition doesn't *do* anything. What is the actual issue you're trying to solve? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a loop to *build* a filter condition - ie concatenate as string.  Is this the case?

Comment: @freedomn-m  hmm, I think this describes it the best.. :-(

Comment: @TylerRoper  this above s a very reduced sample. A more complex one can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/ukdmvy5e/203/
Outbound and Inbound each means a SEGMENT. I need to find the fares where OUT- and INBOUND matches a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to satisfy your condiitions, where:

1. The `#static` element has a value of `'10'` and
2. The first three `.sample` elements all have a value of `'1'`,

...you can use the following condition:

```
// Get first 3 `.sample` elements, and see if their values are '1'
const $matchingSamples = $('.sample').filter(function(i) {
    return i <= 2 && this.value === '1';
});

// Combine all your conditions
const condition = $('#static').val() === '10' && $matchingSamples.length === 3;
```

The `condition` variable will be equivalent to:

```
$('#static').val() === '10' &&
  $('.sample:eq(0)').val() === '1') && 
  $('.sample:eq(1)').val() === '1') && 
  $('.sample:eq(2)').val() === '1')
```

---

Of course, you can rewrite the logic above to not use jQuery at all, in ES6:

```
const samples = document.querySelectorAll('.sample');
const matchingSamples = Array.from(samples).filter((sample, i) => {
    return i <= 2 && sample.value === '1';
})

const condition = document.getElementById('static').value === '10' && matchingSamples.length === 3;
```

---

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const numberOfSamplesToCheck = 3;

function checkValues() {
  const $matchingSamples = $('.sample').filter(function(i) {
    return i <= numberOfSamplesToCheck - 1 && this.value === '1';
  });
  
  const condition = $('#static').val() === '10' && $matchingSamples.length === numberOfSamplesToCheck;
  console.log(condition);
}

checkValues();

$(':input').on('change', checkValues);
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="static" value="10" type="number" />
<input class="sample" value="1" type="number" />
<input class="sample" value="1" type="number" />
<input class="sample" value="1" type="number" />
```

Comment: That looks promising! I have a few more filters to set than just "#static" and ".sample". But I guess I can repeat the way you've solved the problem. Thanks a lot, I am on this problem for multiple days now!

Comment: What does .filter(function(i) { ... } mean here, what does the i stand for in i <= 2? Is that the amount of filter conditions?

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi That selects the first 3 elements, i.e. `eq(0)`, `eq(1)`, and `eq(2)` in each iteration.

Comment: ah ok, that can vary later

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi Of course. I will update my code snippet so that the number of elements to check can be stored as a variable.

Comment: You're a star, Terry! Thanks a lot for the time you've invested - that's so helpful